# Quero pegar o valor de um campo de formulário e passar para outro

Tags: javascript, html5

Tentei fazer isso em JS

```js
function diaSemana() {
  var data = new Date();
  var dia = data.getDay();
  var dias = ['Domingo', 'Segunda', 'Terça', 'Quarta', 'Quinta', 'Sexta', 'Sábado'];

  var p = document.getElementById('campo').value = dias[dia];
  return p;
}
diaSemana();
```

```html
<p>Estes são os respetivos campos, e queria pegar o valor da data e passar em simultâneo quando escolho um dia para campo de leitura.</p>
<form>
  <label>Data:</label>
  <input type="date" id="data">
  
  <label>Dia da Semana:</label>
  <input type="text" id="campo" readonly>
</form>
```

```
  
     function diaSemana() {     
       var data = new Date();
       var dia = data.getDay();
       var dias = ['Domingo', 'Segunda', 'Terça', 'Quarta', 'Quinta', 'Sexta', 'Sábado'];     
       var p = document.getElementById('p').innerHTML = dias[dia];
       return p;
     }
    diaSemana();
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar o evento `onchange` para saber quando o input date for alterado e poder atualizar o campo com o dia da semana. Veja no exemplo abaixo:

```js
const inputData = document.querySelector('#data');
const inputDiaSemana = document.querySelector('#campo');
const diasSemana = [
  'Domingo',
  'Segunda',
  'Terça',
  'Quarta',
  'Quinta', 
  'Sexta',
  'Sábado'
];

inputData.addEventListener('change', () => {
    const [dia, mes, ano] = inputData.value.split('/');
    const objDate = new Date(ano, mes - 1, dia);

    inputDiaSemana.value = diasSemana[objDate.getDay()]; 
});
```

```html
<p>Estes são os respetivos campos,
e queria pegar o valor da data e passar
em simultâneo quando escolho um dia para
campo de leitura.</p>
<form>
  <label>Data:</label>
  <input type="date" id="data" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy">
  
  <label>Dia da Semana:</label>
  <input type="text" id="campo" readonly>
</form>
```

Comment: Farei a implementação do script, o ano e o mês serão dinâmicos com PHP.

Comment: Legal Willeu! Então este script deve mudar um pouquinho. Se houver problemas poste novamente, abs  ;)

Comment: Está bem, Marcelo... 

Comment: `  
  const objDate = new Date(ano, mes - 1, dia); 

`

Queria uma recomendação de como tornar isso dinâmico, tentei e não resultou.
Eu sinto que está funcionalidade dever ser criada com JS em contraste com o PHP, que já fiz uma, todavia não tem a interação e acessibilidade que eu desejava.

Ficaria grato, @MarceloVismari

Comment: Não entendi muito bem. O valor do `objDate` vêm do PHP? algo do tipo: `const objDate = new Date(<%= $ano %>, <%= $mes %>, <%= $dia %>);`?